# What is the relationship between Oracle.Web and Oracle.DataAccess in-re Asp.Net Forms Auth?

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I'm using oracle asp.net Forms Auth in my web app.  The asp.net Membership/Role/Profile provider classes use Oracle.web.dll, and the connection string for these use Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

Now I want to change to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll for the main application's data connection.

I made this change, and the app's main data connections work fine.  However when any of the Forms Membership/Role/Profile methods are called, I get errors saying "Failed to load Oracle.DataAccess.dll".

I pointed the Forms Auth connections strings to a string using the Managed provider, but the Membership/Role/Profile parts seem to rely on Oracle.Web, which somehow looks for Oracle.DataAccess instead of the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

Can anyone shed light on this please?
Thanks,
--Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem and used Reflector to check references.

Yes, Oracle.Web.dll references Oracle.DataAccess.dll which further references OCI. Since OCI different for 64bit and 32bit one actually needs to install the appropriate Oracle client.

Hope that there will be a Oracle.Web version, that relies on Oracle.ManagedDataAcccess.dll soon.

The advantage of thru the use of oracle.manageddataaccess is kind of lost if one relies on profiles or membership providers.

Comment: thank you for verifying this.  We are just going to write our own methods to deal with Profile data so we can relieve ourselves from this conflict.  MS made kind of a goofy data model for the profile properties...but we've tackled that and the rest is gravy.

Comment: Just want to add that **oracle.web  4.121.2.1** now depends on Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and no longer on oracle.dataaccess. Therefore the installed client 32/64 does no longer matter for accessing data thru oracle.web.

Comment: thank you for that, I know this is late response.  We never got the time to re-write to avoid this mess.  Anyway, I'm now trying Oracle Client 4.122.19.1 (we upgraded to Oracle "19c" which I guess is just 12.19.  Anyway, looking at Process Explorer, Oracle.DataAccess is still being loaded, even though I've removed every possible shred of reference to that dll in the web.config and in any of the Using statements--nothing wants it, the DLL is deleted from bin, etc, but it is still needed.  And still causing issue.